# Get list based on occurrences in unknown number of sublists

Tags: python, list

I'm looking for a way to make a list containing list (`a` below) into a single list (`b` below) with 2 conditions:

1. The order of the new list (`b`) is based on the number of times the value has occurred in some of the lists in `a`.
2. A value can only appear once

Basically turn `a` into `b`:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4], [4,5,6]]
# value 4 occurs 3 times in list a and gets first position
# value 2 occurs 2 times in list a and get second position and so on...
b = [4,2,3,1,5,6]
```

I figure one could do this with `set` and some list magic. But can't get my head around it when `a` can contain any number of list. The `a` list is created based on user input (I guess that it can contain between 1 - 20 list with up 200-300 items in each list).

My trying something along the line with `[set(l) for l in a]` but don't know how to perform `set(l) & set(l)....` to get all matched items.

Is possible without have a `for` loop iterating sublist count * items in sublist times?

Comment: Can you describe in more detail how you get `b` from `a`? I'm having trouble parsing your first sentence.

Comment: Updated the question to clarify it. Hope I made my self a bit clearer.

Comment: I think this makes sense. So `[['a','b','c'], ['b'], ['c']]` would map to `['b','c','a']`. In this case does it matter which order `'b'` and `'c'` are in?

Comment: @Wilduck: precisely. And the order of `'b'` and `'c'` doesn't matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is probably the closest you're going to get:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)

for sub in outer:
  for val in sub:
    d[val] += 1

print sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda k: d[k], reverse = True)
# Output: [4, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6]
```

There is an off chance that the order of elements that appear an identical number of times may be indeterminate - the output of `d.keys()` is not ordered.

Comment: Many thanks, worked exactly like I wanted! Curious, do you know how it holds up with large lists? It worked find on a [[30n], [140n]] list.

Comment: @fredrik - it should hold up reasonably well.  The generation of the intermediary dictionary doesn't loop any more than necessary and is O(n).  The sorting time will depend on the total number of distinct values, but python's built in sorting algorithm is pretty slick.  Unless you're dealing with extremely large sub lists or huge numbers of distinct entries it should be fine.  That was actually my main qualm with one of the other answers - `-sum(x.count(y) for x in a)` is an extremely heavy calculation with a lot of implied looping.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
a = [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4], [4,5,6]]
s = set()
for l in a:
    s.update(l)
print s 
#set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
b = list(s)
```

This will add each list to the set, which will give you a unique set of all elements in all the lists. If that is what you are after.

Edit. To preserve the order of elements in the original list, you can't use sets.

```
a = [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4], [4,5,6]]
b = []
for l in a:
    for i in l:
        if not i in b:
            b.append(i)
print b
#[1,2,3,4,5,6] - The same order as the set in this case, since thats the order they appear in the list
```

Comment: Almost (a bit on the way). But I need the order of `b` to be based on the number of occurrences in `a`. I updated the question

Comment: Ah, then you should do basically the same thing, but with a dict instead of a set.

a = [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4], [4,5,6]]
s = defaultdict(0)
for l in a:
    for item in l:
        s[item] = s[item] + 1
print s 
#set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
b = [pair[0] for pair in sorted(s.items(), key = lambda pair:pair[1]]

Comment: Based on your updated question about the order being based on the number of appearances of a number, the answers below have it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
all_items = set(itertools.chain(*a))
b = sorted(all_items, key = lambda y: -sum(x.count(y) for x in a))
```

Comment: This is succinct, but the `-sum(x.count(y) for x in a))` is pretty expensive isn't it?

Comment: -1 Try this on a list of a few thousand with lists of a few thousand; a `defaultdict` is *much* better.

Comment: @Ethan, yes. Although a collection.Counter is even better.

Comment: @Ethan, no. I might but my installed version of python isn't new enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
from collections import defaultdict

def list_by_count(lists):
    data_stream = itertools.chain.from_iterable(lists)
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for item in data_stream:
        counts[item] += 1
    return [item for (item, count) in 
            sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))]
```

Having the x[0] in the sort key ensures that items with the same count are in some kind of sequence as well.